# ScrollView inside View or Vice Versa?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I am working in iOS and cannot find if there is a definitive answer to this.

I have a screen, the entire thing will scroll (not just part of it is scrolling at the top). I am using Storyboards to build this and the content is bigger than the screen size. Is the best way to do this with:

This is all inside of a UIViewController.

- The content inside a View (child) inside a fullscreen ScrollView (parent) and set content size of ScrollView as the View's frame.
- The content inside a ScrollView (child) inside a fullscreen View (parent) and set content size of ScrollView as its frame and then its new frame as the View's frame.
- Just a ScrollView as the first child of the ViewController and set its content size as its frame and then its frame as the screen size (which I would need to check at runtime?)

All of these methods seem to work, but they make other things easier/harder (moving content for keyboard, etc.). Is it simply a matter of opinion or is there a "best/correct" method?

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: I can share code for both...and both work. I was more curious if there was a standard that I wasn't aware of.  Additionally, I am using storyboards, so I am not sure how the code would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set content size bigger than your view. Then It will scroll.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That has nothing to do with my question. All my above examples are working, I am wondering which one is the "best" or "correct" way of doing it.